# Most popular question and answer and forum sites in Chinese

Tags: learning, resources, reading

What social networks exist on the Chinese internet, that allow people to meet and discuss things on any topic, or ask questions, like on Quora. I am learning Chinese and would like to practice. Any useful resources pointed out besides this question and answer site and dating sites would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess somebody flag to close because this is opinion base.  Although I will suggest something like Zhihu on general stuff,  Douban on contents(books, music, movie, article) comments,  but those are not a good place to learn Chinese, as it may contains confusing jargon and slang.

Answer (score 2):

Check out 知乎 - just type that into google along with any random Chinese word of your choice, to find a load of threads containing that word - it's a great way to practice reading.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to ask a question in Chinese about some topic such as life and culture?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson I am not user2137196. If you want to ask a question in Chinese, then you may register for an account on the website. Then, you ask a question in Chinese. People respond. 知乎 is based on the Quora model. So, you can tag your question with 生活 or 文化 or 生活方式.

Answer (score 0):

百度知道 is also a Q&A website. You can find all sorts of information on there.

Answer (score 0):

Quora -> 知乎 （share your stories that you just make up）

facebook -> 人人（almost died）

twitter -> 微博 （to be a VIP follower）

reddit -> 贴吧（not allow overseas）

youtube -> 优酷（You can even watch videos between ADs)